# how to pin element relative to the body but out of page flow?

Tags: css

I'm really not a front end developer, but

- I need to create an element (depicted below in red)
- that remains relative to the page (as indicated by the line, so it basically stays in the same place on the page when I change the window proportions)
- but is out of the flow of the rest of the page (so that the fieldsets, starting with "cash management" sit under the "Investing Magazine" title )

How do I do this please?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably a few ways to do this but here's a couple for you.

**Option 1 using floats:**

Treat the main content and the red side block as two columns. Float them both, give them a width and put them in a container.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
        <h1>Investing Magazine</h1>
        <p>Your content here</p>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <p>The side block here</p>
    </aside>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row:before, .row:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: table;
    line-height: 0; }

.row:after { clear: both; }
.row { *zoom: 1; }

section { 
    float: left;
    width: 80%; }

aside {
    float: left;
    width:20%;
    background: red; }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sntmW/

**Option 2 using positioning:**

Absolutely position the red block to place it exactly where you want.

HTML

```
<section>
  <h1>Investing Magazine</h1>
  <p>Your content here</p>
</section>
<aside>
  <p>The side block here</p>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
section { width: 80%; }

aside {
    position: absolute;
    width:20%;
    top:0; right:0;
    background: red; }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CHr7A/